# Refugee crises before 20th century

Tags: war, migration

Most refugee crises I am aware of happened since the turn of the 20th century. Is there any documented history of refugee crises before? Do we know if wars comparable in intensity and casualties before the 20th century caused similar magnitudes of refugees? If not, what were some of the reasons?

Here is an [interesting visual](https://www.washingtonpost.com/graphics/world/historical-migrant-crisis/) but it only covers since WW2.

Comment: One of the largest in Jewish history (albeit not resultant of war) was the expulsion of Jews from the Iberian Peninsula at the end of the 15th century. Approximately 80,000 Jews (the numbers are disputed) sought asylum elsewhere in Europe, many flooding into Italy and the Netherlands in particular.

Comment: [Bar Kokhba revolt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bar_Kokhba_revolt)

Comment: [Babylonian exile](https://www.britannica.com/event/Babylonian-Exile)? The elimination of the angles by the Saxons? The harrying of the North? The Irish Potato famine? British patriots displaced by the US revolutionary war?  The Mongols? Ireland?  There is something I'm not understanding about this quesiton.

Comment: I'm not sure what confuses you. I was asking about pre 20th century history of refugee crises. your comment lists some examples but is condescending in the way that it presumes i should know about those events already, which i didn't. so it is helpful but in a condescending way

Comment: also consider this: "Do we know if wars comparable in intensity and casualties before the 20th century caused similar magnitudes of refugees?" it is asking for an analysis of whether wars before 20th century generally caused as many refugees as, say, Syrian war does and why.

Comment: I'd say the migration period during/after the fall of the roman empire might have been the greatest refugee crisis of all. And in a broad sense it was also caused by a "war".

Comment: Why the downvote? I think this is an excellent question: it concerns history and it asks for documentation. Not sure how it could be improved, to be honest.

Comment: There was no shortage of [pogroms and expulsions of Jews](http://www.eretzyisroel.org/~jkatz/expulsions.html) in the past. The [Romani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_Romani_history) had a bunch of those too, on a shorter time scale. The [expulsion of the Moriscos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expulsion_of_the_Moriscos) also comes to mind. If you dig deep enough you'll come across all sorts of colorful examples of displaced populations: invader moves in for some reason or another, or a disaster arrives (Maya? Indus Valley? Petroglyph Sites?), and off goes the existing population.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genocides_in_history might be a good starting point for further research.

Comment: Note: if looking for refugee crises that are "comparable in intensity" to those experienced in the 20th century, you also need to bear in mind the relative size of the world's population. According to the information at the end of [this video](http://waitbutwhy.com/2015/06/spectacular-video-putting-wwii-deaths-perspective.html), the most harrowing war in history may have been the An Lushan rebellion in the 8th century - but only when adjusting for planet's population at the time.

Comment: Could people stop answering in comments and answer in answers?  amphibient: Are you only interested in answers regarding refugees due to wars, or for any cause for a significant migration?  Your title is general but in your question you refer to wars as root cause.  Maybe edit the title to get those two points to align.

Answer (score 2):

The Zoroastrian emigration from Persia to Bombay is one.

See this article for more details: [Parsi (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsi).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to all the examples listed in the comments:

One of the most famous and studied example is the Visigoths, Ostrogoths (and other tribes) fleeing the Huns in the 4-5th centuries AD and entering the Roman empire. Any book covering fall of the (Western) Roman empire will discuss this in great detail.